# Verificação atributo nulo no @Html.DisplayNameFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso verificar se o atributo de uma classe é nulo. Se ele for nulo, gostaria de esconder seu label. Abaixo segue um exemplo de como está sendo exibido hoje:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O atributo ***DataFinalizacao*** veio nulo, portanto não exibiria seu label. Abaixo a estrutura do códico HTML:

```
<div class="label label-primary">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataSolucao)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DataSolucao)
 </div>

 <div class="label label-primary">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataFinalizacao)
 </div>
 <div class="display-field">
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DataFinalizacao)
 </div>
```

Como devo verificar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo:

```
@if (Model.DataFinalizacao != null) 
{
    <div class="label label-primary">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataFinalizacao)
     </div>
     <div class="display-field">
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DataFinalizacao)
     </div>
}
```

Comment: Assim mesmo. Funcionou.